# javascript botton that parses json file from an url not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to show the text from a json file I got from an url with an button, here's what I have now:

```
<p id="text">Show Text Here</p>
<button class="button">Article 1</button>
<script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">

$("button").click(function(){
$.getJSON("http://localhost:3001/api/reading", function(data, status){
  var obj=JSON.parse(data);
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =obj;
  console.log(obj);
});
});
</script>
```

And the json file was sent by doing following:

```
app.get('/api/reading', function(req, res){
result = {}
var file_path = path.join(__dirname,'Readings/1.txt');
fs.readFile(file_path, "utf8", function(err, data) {
  if(err){
    result['err'] = true;
  }else{
    result['text'] = data;
  }
  res.json(result);
  });
});
```

But the button is not working, any advice on how i can fix it?

Comment: Pretty sure that's a parse error since you return an object from the server-side and try to parse it on the client-side. Check your console for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use close mark `</script>` correctly

```
<p id="text">Show Text Here</p>
<button class="button">Article 1</button>
<script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Then I recommend use all jQuery since you just include jQuery, why not.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:3001/api/reading", function(data, status){
    $("#text").text(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
});
```

Comment: omg thanks i was the close mark typo that's stopping it from working! now console log shows that it's getting the json file  from url when i click the button but the target paragraph is not replaced

Answer (score 0):

API is returning *JSON* response so `data` will be of type `object` so you need to convert your object to string and then assign

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:3001/api/reading", function(data, status) {
    //as data is already object you need to convert it to text
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text">Show Text Here</p>
<button class="button">Article 1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting a console.log inside the click function or step through in debugger will show that the button does respond to a click.

It does look like you are trying to assign JSON to a string without parsing it. Are you getting any console errors?

To check if the $.getJson gives you an error on the request add the `.fail()` like this to see what the issue is:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:3001/api/reading", function(data, status){
  var obj=JSON.parse(data);
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =obj;
}).fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
});
```